# Ruby : Time to be stored in an array

Tags: ruby

I have a todo list .

It has functions for popping up a window when the time for the todo has elapsed

I just want to know how do I store the times when the todo item was prepared and how do I monitor it ?

Comment: Can we have some code which you have tried?

Answer (score 3):

When you are creating a todo item, store a time. You can create a time object using `Time.new` in Ruby. For more details you can refer to the given [link](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-c-new).